# Has expressValidator changed in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, express-validator

This is a nodejs file
The code takes in email name and other things validates it and stores it in the database. Now as far as i know we can use app.use(expressValidator()) but here the definition has changed and its a little confusing

```
const express =require("express")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const path = require('path')
const expressValidator = require('express-validator')
const mongojs = require('mongojs')
const db = mongojs('studentdata', ['users'])


const app = express()

const Port = 3000

//view engine
app.set('view engine','ejs')
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'))

//middleware bodyParser
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}))

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')))


app.use( (req,res,next) => {
    res.locals.errors = null;
    next()
})

app.use(expressValidator({
    errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
        var namespace = param.split('.')
        , root    = namespace.shift()
        , formParam = root;
  
      while(namespace.length) {
        formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
      }
      return {
        param : formParam,
        msg   : msg,
        value : value
      };
    }
  }));
  
const users = []


app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    db.users.find( (err,docs) => {
        res.render("index", {
            title:'Students',
            users: docs
        })
    })
   
})

app.post('/users/add', (req,res) => {
    req.checkBody('first_name','First Name is Required').notEmpty()
    req.checkBody('last_name','last Name is Required').notEmpty()
    req.checkBody('email','email is Required').notEmpty()
    req.checkBody('d_o_b','Date of birth is Required').notEmpty()

    var errors = req.validationErrors()

    if(errors){
        res.render("index", {
            title:'Students',
            users: users,
            errors: errors
    
        })

    }else{
        var newUser = {
            email : req.body.email,
            first_name : req.body.first_name,
            last_name : req.body.last_name,
            d_o_b :req.body.d_o_b
        }
        db.users.insert(newUser, (err,result) => {
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
            }
            res.redirect('/')
        })

    }
        
      
    } )


app.listen(Port, () => {
    console.log('Server conned on '+Port)
})
```

I am confused on with this part of the code

```
app.use(expressValidator({
    errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
        var namespace = param.split('.')
        , root    = namespace.shift()
        , formParam = root;
  
      while(namespace.length) {
        formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
      }
      return {
        param : formParam,
        msg   : msg,
        value : value
      };
    }
  }));
```

I searched the internet and I was unable to understand the parameters of this expressValidators.
And also is there a documentation of this expressValidator?

Answer (score 0):

Express validator is a npm package. You can find its doc [here](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-result-api.html)

It looks like your errorFormatter attribute correspond to the `.formatWith` method.

Comment: is there a documentation i can refer to?

Comment: I put the link of their doc in my answer. If you have any issue with the doc you should look at their github repository and maybe raise an issue (https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator)

Comment: @Har.D did you resolve the issue? I am also having the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the errorFormatter attribute in the current version of express-validator(6.9.2) got deprecated.

Therefore, please install express-validator ver 4 using npm:

```
npm install --save express-validator@4
```